# How can I update the xml node values using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml file of following form

```
         <input>
            <node1>No Update<node1>
            <node2>No Update<node2>
            <node3>No Update<node3>
            <node4>Data<node4>
         <input>
```

My requirement is to update the values of those nodes which has data 'No Update' into empty string, so that the desired output will be

```
         <input>
            <node1><node1>
            <node2><node2>
            <node3><node3>
            <node4>Data<node4>
         <input>
```

How can I achieve it using xslt, can somebody help please.

Comment: Thanks it helps, i have got one more doubt here. The above input xml is the output of some xslt transformations. If I add the above code to my existing xsl at the last, will it remove the values? These <input> xml node is copied from another xml based on some conditions. Can we remove the values while copying?

Answer (score 2):

Use this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[text() = 'No Update']/text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And if you don't want self-enclosing tags in output change the template to:

```
<xsl:template match="*[text() = 'No Update']/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good answer, +1. Which would also be same with xsl:value-of `<xsl:template match="*[text() = 'No Update']/text()"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use this short(er) transformation -- the same idea of overriding the identity rule**, but matching **only** the necessary text-nodes -- not element nodes.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()[. = 'No Update']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML (corrected to become a well-formed XML document):**

```
<input>
    <node1>No Update</node1>
    <node2>No Update</node2>
    <node3>No Update</node3>
    <node4>Data</node4>
</input>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<input>
   <node1/>
   <node2/>
   <node3/>
   <node4>Data</node4>
</input>
```